# posting checkboxes boolean class from jquery formdata

Tags: c#, ajax

I have a c# class ReportSettings with several boolean values in the controller.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ReportSettings(int searchId, ReportSettings reportSettings)
```

I have a form of all inputs of type="checkbox"

```
$(modal).one("submit", "#ReportSettings", function () {
       
        event.preventDefault();
        reportSettings = new FormData();
        var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
        $.each(checkbox, function (key, val) {
            var value = $(this).prop('checked') ? 1: 0;
            $(this).val(value);
            console.log($(this).attr('name') + " " + $(this).val())
            reportSettings.append($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val())
        });
       

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: urls.reportSettings,
            data: { searchId: $('input[Name="SearchId"]').val(), reportSettings: reportSettings },
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }).done(function (data) {
            closeModal(modal)
            
            $("#message").html("Report Settings Saved").show();
        })
    })
```

How do I get these checkbox values to post into a class of boolean objects?